# Calling multiple functions on "Onsubmit"

Tags: php, javascript, function

I have a form through which i am finding distance between two locations.
right now my form works fine.i have used.

```
<form method="get" name="f1" id="f1" class="formular" action="findcars.php" onsubmit="showLocation(); return false;">
```

Now i want to validate all form inputs.. so i have added the function validate(); like this

```
<form method="get" name="f1" id="f1" class="formular" action="findcars.php" onsubmit="validate(); showLocation(); return false;">
```

But this is not working..pls..help, how should i call this validate() function.

Thanks.

Comment: try this `javascript:validate();`

Comment: @Sumit yes,i have made validate(); , but the problem is that script doesn't call that function

Comment: @SumitBijvani the prefix `javascript:` in `on…` attributes is a mistake. It's never needed, it doesn't do anything (it doesn't cause syntax error only because it happens to match break/continue labels syntax)

Comment: can you please write the code here for function validate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try this

```
<form method="get" name="f1" id="f1" class="formular" action="findcars.php" onsubmit="myFunction(); return false;">

<script>
    myFunction function () {
    validate(); 
    showLocation();
}
</script>
```

Comment: still doesn't work...& another problem is that on showLocation(); function, i have redirected page...so it calls showlocation() & redirects , but not calling validate();

Comment: make the  showLocation(); as callback function for the validate() then it will be called after validation finished.

Answer (score 1):

try doing

```
validate() && showLocation();
```

or, calling one master function which then runs a chain:

```
masterFunction();

function masterFunction() {
  validate();
  showLocation();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form method="get" name="f1" id="f1" class="formular" action="findcars.php" onsubmit="validate(); showLocation(); return false;">  
    <button id="search-submit" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function validate(){
    alert('validate');
}
function showLocation(){
    alert('Location');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do in this way..

```
<form method="get" name="f1" id="f1" class="formular" action="findcars.php" onsubmit="return myvalidations();">

function myvalidations() {
validate(); 
showLocation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrange functions like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="function1();function2();" value="Call2Functions" />

  function func1(){
     //--- some logic
     func2();
   }

   function func2(){
    //--- some logic
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First call only validate() method if return true then call second method inside it. like below

```
function validate(){
// ok is output of your validate method whether true or false
if(ok){
showLocation();
}
else{
return false;
}
}
```